If every Purana is written in different Kalpa, then the incidents of Ramayana written in these Puranas are also according to the same Kalpa?
Every Purana contains a description of all the incarnations, and every Purana is written in a different Kalpa, so how can we understand which event has happened when?

Matsya Purana lists which Purana belongs to which Kalpa -

Padma Purana - Padma Kalpa
Vishnu Purana - Varaha Kalpa
Vayu Purana - Sveta Kalpa
Bhagavata Purana - Sarasvata Kalpa
Agni Purana - Isana Kalpa
Brahmavaivarta Purana - Rathantara Kalpa
Linga Purana - Agneya Kalpa.
Varaha Purana - Manava Kalpa.
Skanda Purana - Satpurusa Kalpa
Vamana Purana - Kurma Kalpa
Kurma Purana - Lakshmi Kalpa
Garuda Purana - Garuda Kalpa.
Brahmanda Purana - events from future Kalpas.


Chapter 53, Matsya Purana.


so the puranas are according to different kalpas, the incidents of Ramayan written in those puranas had also plcked up from their respective puranas??

@Vedant Jadhav - Yes the Puranas contain Ramayana stories from different Kalpas.
